# Why doesn't the Request.ServerVariables collection show all properties, like DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was reading the docs on [URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#interaction-with-iis-output-caching), and it gets to a part where it explains the use of server variables, and it mentions `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Since the other variables were familiar, I wrote a simple script to display them all:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
foreach (string name in Request.ServerVariables)
{
    Response.Write(name + ": " + Request[name] + "<br/>");
}
%>
```

To my surprise, `DOCUMENT_ROOT` isn't displayed. And to my bigger surprise, it **is** displayed when you access it directly:

```
<%= Request.ServerVariables["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] %>
```

> E:\WebSites\MyWebSite

It is almost identical as `APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH`, except `DOCUMENT_ROOT` doesn't have a back slash at the end.

I tried debugging an ASP.NET site and check what is inside `Request.ServerVariables`, but I see the same variables, and no trace of `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Is this a hidden variable? Are there any other variables like this? How do I list them all?

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is (it probably isn't), but:   [`Request.ServerVariables` is for classic ASP code.  In ASP.NET, use the `HttpRequest.ServerVariables` property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)